# margin-bottom is calculated differently in Opera

Tags: html, css, margin, opera

I have a div with relative position and a children div with position absolute.

```html
<div id="container" class="out">
    <div id="inside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
#inside {
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    right:25px;
    bottom:25px;
    margin-bottom:24px;
}
```

Chrome, Safari and Firefox seem to work correctly but Opera browser (in Mac) is calculating margin-bottom twice.

This a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fw9wc0o/1/

Is this a bug or am I missing some property?

Comment: Why margin-bottom on a positioned div?

Comment: I saw this fiddle on Chrome, Safari, FF and Opera on a mac, they look the exactly same

Comment: Really? I am not seeing the same margin. Yosemite and just downloaded Opera today.

Comment: Do you want to fight this bug or use a workaround?

Comment: I want to confirm if its a bug or I am missing some property. A fix for Opera if exists is what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the Opera browser offered in the App Store is version 12, more than a year and a half outdated (actual is 25). Downloading it directly from their website and opening the jsfiddle doesnt show any conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Opera browser does not overrides the **bottom** property with **margin-bottom**... so it seems that margin bottom doubles by mistake in the browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As an improvement, please add links or references to your information. It backups your answer with additional content.