# css calc() is not working in opera

Tags: html, css, browser, opera

I have this divs:

```
<div id="outside">
    <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outside {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
.inside {
    width:calc(100% - 50px);
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLz08wu2/)

Chrome, Firefox and Safari (mac) work as expected, however Opera (mac) is not recognising the calc() property,and ignoring it.

Is this a bug? I posted a similar problem in Opera [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660252/margin-bottom-is-calculated-differently-in-opera).

Comment: What are you trying do exactly? Maybe someone can help you finding the alternate way instead of using calc.

Comment: Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc and http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-calc-function/ for calc support

Comment: Interesting, caniuse says it works correctly in Opera:　http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc  But the last link you posted says its not supported in Opera

Comment: I would prefer mozilla developer network for trusting the browser support and it's quite visible in your example. Anyway, did you tried using padding on 'outside' instead of adjusting dimension in 'inside' container?

Comment: @KK which version of Opera are you using?

Comment: @YemSalat I am using safari web developer tools to mock opera 11.11 on mac. And it's showing error on calc property.

Comment: @KK `calc()` is not supported in Opera 11.x

Comment: @KK you can install the latest Opera on a Mac by the way.

Comment: @YemSalat Yeah but does this work on latest opera without any issue? PS: I don't have mac right now :\

Comment: @KK, it does, new Opera uses Blink - the same rendering engine as Chrome, so whatever works on Chrome - will also work on new Opera.

Comment: @Alvaro:maybe you need to update opera if you are using 11.x version. Try if that works. But for 11.x version, calc won't work

Comment: 12.15 is the latest version for mac (App Store), which Im using. I learnt today different OS have different versions. So should I guess its a bug only happening in Mac, right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the Opera browser offered in the App Store is version 12, more than a year and a half outdated (actual is 25). Downloading it directly from their website and opening the jsfiddle doesnt show any conflict. Thanks for the comments.